# Haskell, Editline, segfault

Tags: haskell

Пишу программу, которая использует библиотеку Editline. Код примерно таков:

```
import System.Console.Editline.Readline (initialize, readline, addHistory)
import Control.Monad (forever)

-- тут все остальное

main = do initialize
          forever $ do x <- readline "$ "
                       let y = (\(Just p) -> p) x
                       addHistory y
                       someFunc y --что-то делаем с полученым текстом
```

Так вот, при попытке выйти из программы, нажав Ctrl+C, она вылетает с сегфолтом. ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: А как она должна реагировать на CTRL+C?

Comment: Должна — исключением Control.Exception.

Comment: а "сегфолт" и неотловленное Control.Exception -- вещи разные?

Comment: Конечно же.